# How to save image from url using picasso library in android?

Tags: android, image, save

I have stored images on server, now i want to download that image from android code. I am using picasso library for loading images from server.

But i don't know how to download and save it in my SDCard (only using Picasso library or some other library).
So, anyone suggest me any working code !!

i am using this code

```
Picasso.with(this).load("server url").fetch(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError() {

        }
    });
```

Comment: If you want to save it to specific folder then use call back with _Target_ for picasso which will return bitmap and you can save that bitmap to specific folder

Comment: i have used callback also, but i don't know from where i can get image.

Comment: In _onBitmapLoaded_ method you can get bitmap which will be your image.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I have used Target like Picasso.with(this).load("server url").into(myTarget);

Answer (score 0):

```
    //save image
    public static void imageDownload(Context ctx, String url){
        Picasso.with(ctx)
                .load("http://blog.concretesolutions.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Android1.png")
                .into(getTarget(url));
    }

    //target to save
    private static Target getTarget(final String url){
        Target target = new Target(){

            @Override
            public void onBitmapLoaded(final Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/" + url);
                        try {
                            file.createNewFile();
                            FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, ostream);
                            ostream.flush();
                            ostream.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Log.e("IOException", e.getLocalizedMessage());
                        }
                    }
                }).start();

            }

            @Override
            public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

            }
```

Use above code for saving the bitmap in your External storage ..Please make sure your dynamic permissions and Manifest file have been set up properly.Please follow this discussion [Saving image from url using Picasso?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32799353/saving-image-from-url-using-picasso)

Comment: yes next time give the url where you found the solution. [http://stackoverflow.com/a/32799659/3763848](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32799659/3763848)

Comment: Cant you do better with Picasso? Pretty strange that Picasso converts a jpg file to a bitmap first. Or a png file. Quite strange. It should just deliver the bytes of the file. Or yet better save the received bytes to file directly for you. Can it be done?

Comment: `file.createNewFile();`. Better remove that. It serves nothing.

Comment: `ostream.flush();
                            ostream.close();` Not needed. BitmapFactory has already done that.