# bitmap return null when converted from url to bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, drawable, firebase-storage

I know there is lots of question regarding the same problem and i have tried many solution like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415619/how-to-convert-a-bitmap-to-drawable-in-android) but i am still getting the empty string.
here is my code

```
try {
      URL url = new URL(myUrl);
      InputStream in = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
      BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(in,1024*8);
      ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

      int len=0;
      byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
      while((len = bis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, len);
      }
      out.close();
      bis.close();

      byte[] data = out.toByteArray();
      Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);

      d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bmp);

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      d = getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.background);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```

> myUrl is firebase storage url

Comment: Any reason to not use something like picasso ( http://square.github.io/picasso/ ) ?

Comment: piccaso and glide are used to setimage in imageView but i only want drawable from url

Comment: You can get bitmap from Picasso and convert into drawable

Comment: how? @BurhanuddinRashid can you please explain with a piece of code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32799353/saving-image-from-url-using-picasso

Answer (score 1):

Add Picassso libarary in your gradle file

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

Than download image using picasso like this :

```
 Picasso.with(this)
.load(myUrl)
.into(new Target() {
      @Override
      public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) { 

              //Convert your drawable here
              d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);

      }

      @Override
      public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

      }

      @Override
      public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

      }
 });
```

Comment: still getting "" blank string in bitmap

Comment: How you are supposed get blank string in bitmap object...Have you kept the INTERNET permission

Comment: Yes i have given internet permission, i am getting url from internet i have checked its not returning null but when i  am getting drawable from that url its giving me blank string