# PIcasso and WallpaperManager

Tags: android, picasso

I want to set image from the internet as wallpaper, but WallpaperManager works only with Id of image, which is Int type.

My solution is to download image from internet Picaso

```
Picasso.from(mContext).load(url).into(imageView);
```

and after to find ID of  that image and put it in WallpaperManager

```
WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager
                = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getContext());
        try {
            myWallpaperManager.setResource(loadedImage)
 } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Question: How to find ID of that image?

Comment: You need to save the image into a target instead of setting into an ImageView. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32799353/saving-image-from-url-using-picasso

Answer (score 2):

you can try this:

```
Picasso.with(this) .load(imageUrl).centerCrop() .into(new Target() { 
 @Override 
  public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) { 
      myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap)
}
```